# How to read a json file with NextJS and App Router from the server

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I've a little test app to study next.js and now I'm trying to read data from a json file in a server-side funcion.

Ths problem is that is saying that the URL does not exist...
Error: Failed to parse URL from ../data/myfile.json

I've tryed placing the data folder inside src/app/data/myfile.json but it's not working neither.

How can I read that file?

Folder structure:
`src/app/layout.jsx`
`src/app/page.jsx`
`src/data/myfile.json`

Code I've been trying(in page.jsx):

```
export default async function HomePage() {
    const data = await getData();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.somevalue}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("../data/myfile.json");
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do that.
this is default architecture of nextjs 14,

[image]

in api/json/route.ts can you do that

```
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { promises as fs } from "node:fs";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = __dirname.replace(".next/server", "src") + "/readjson.json"; //.next/server is the path to the build folder that is created when you run next command
  const fileBuffer = await fs.readFile(path);
  const json = JSON.parse(fileBuffer.toString());
  return NextResponse.json(json);
}
```

after that can you do that for fetching Data in page.tsx:

```
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/json", {
    cache: "no-cache",
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      {/* <Container getData={getData} /> */}
      <h1>{data.message}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've tryed with the /api/json but it's not working neither, literally I've a simple API endpoint that reponses with a get string if you send a get petition and a post string if you send a post petition but I can't access it in server-side methods. Only in clien-side ones.

If I use "use client" I can make a fetch("/api") if don't it'll throw an error saying that endpoint does not exist

Comment: Can you try my latest edit?

Comment: I'll try when I've some free time ^^

Answer (score 0):

A guide from the Vercel site worked seamlessly for me (link below). It does NOT follow route handlers (api/route.ts) convention.

Method from the guide...

GET function

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

async function getData() {
  const path = process.cwd() + "/app/data/myfile.json"
  const file = await fs.readFile(path, "utf8");
  const data = JSON.parse(file);
  return data;
}
```

Server Component

```
export default async function HomePage() {
  const data = await getData();
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{data.somevalue}</h1>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Since the JSON is already in your app, it is unnecessary to use HTTP protocols, therefore there is no need for the fetch method.

"How to Load Data from a File in Next.js" -
https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route